# Manipulating visibility of SVG elements

Tags: javascript, jsp, svg

I'm making a Java web project, where I want to manipulate some front-end SVG-elements with some javascript.

I'm making a fairly simple drawing of a garage, where I have a shed element coming from a JSP page.

I would like a javascript function, on/off button, where the element can be displayed and not hidden.

Here is my code so far:

```
....
<line x1="<%= Math.abs(wid+20) %>"  y1="0" x2="<%= Math.abs(wid+20) %>" y2="<%= len %>"
style="stroke:#c40d0d;
marker-start: url(#beginArrow);
marker-end: url(#endArrow);"/>  


//this is the start of the part that I want to be toggled on and off with a javascript function
<% if(shed){ %>

<rect x="<%= Math.abs(wid-200) %>" y="0" height="<%= len %>" width="200"
    style="stroke:#000000; stroke-width: 3; fill: none"/>


<rect x="<%= Math.abs(wid-200) %>" y="0" height="10" width="10"
    style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="<%= Math.abs(wid-10) %>" y="0" height="10" width="10"
    style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="<%= Math.abs(wid-200) %>" y="<%= Math.abs(len-10) %>" height="10" width="10"
    style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="<%= Math.abs(wid-10) %>" y="<%= Math.abs(len-10) %>" height="10" width="10"
    style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>

 <text x="<%= Math.abs((wid-200)+(wid/8)) %>" y="<%= Math.abs(len+35) %>" fill="Red"> Skur: 200.0 cm </text>

<line x1="<%= Math.abs(wid-200) %>"  y1="<%= Math.abs(len+20) %>" x2=" 
<%= wid %>" y2="<%= Math.abs(len+20) %>" 
style="stroke:#c40d0d;
marker-start: url(#beginArrow);
    marker-end: url(#endArrow);"/>  

<% } %>

</SVG>
<form action="FrontController?command=DynamicCarportSide" name="order" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="length" value="<%= len %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="width" value="<%= wid %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="shed" value="<%= shed %>">
    <input type="submit" value="Side tegning">
</form>
      <%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using an if Statement to show with or without shed in my jsp, but can a click button be used for displaying it after the page is rendered

I was thinking of something like this.

```
function myFunction() {

var SVGcode ="//insert html code here";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = SVGcode;
}
```

the problem is that the SVG-code is too much, so I don't know what to do here

EDIT:

here is a picture of how it is desired to look, so far I just have a function that writes Hello, when the button is pressed, but I desired to have a toggle-on button, that adds the additional SVG-code

[image: Here is an example of an SVG-drawing without the dynamic data, only dummy data]

Comment: Could you give the rendered HTML markup please?

Comment: Yes how should i display it?

Comment: just copy and paste it in your post

Comment: Wait, I'm not exactly sure, what I should display? The entire SVG file?

Comment: No no, just the HTML that's rendered on your page on your browser

Comment: Here is the link to a codepen file. This is just filled with some dummy data for testing purposes, I will fill in the dynamic data when I get it to work.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MXKYdy?editors=1010

Comment: Ok, what do you want to hide? The whole drawing or just some parts of it?

Comment: Only some parts. I have a boolean variable in my previous jsp page, where i check if a user watned a shed or not, in the variable (if shed).

Comment: I would like a button, that made it so, that can toggled on and off

Comment: Ok, I'll post as quick as possible

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Toggle visibility of a given element

You would like to have a function to hide and display some parts of a SVG element. The method I use actually work for any given HTML element (of object `HTMLElement`). You need to:

1. **give the elements you would like to hide/display a class name**, for instance:

   ```
   <line class="segments" x1="55" y1="55" ... stroke-dasharray: 10 5"/>
   <line class="segments" x1="550" y1="55" ... stroke-dasharray: 10 5"/>
   ```
2. write **a function to toggle the visibility of a given element**:

   - we will create a function `hide()` to hide an `HTMLElement`

     ```
     const hide = e => e.style.display = 'none'
     ```
   - and a `show()` function to show it...

     ```
     const show = e => e.style.display = ''
     ```
   - finally, the function to handle the toggle:

     ```
     const toggleHide = function(selector) {
       [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].forEach(e => e.style.display ? show(e) : hide(e))
     }
     ```
3. Lastly **a trigger to call the function**, we can use a `button`:

   ```
   <button onclick="toggleHide('.frame')">Toggle frame</button>
   ```

   Set the function to call in the `onclick` attribute of the button and give it as argument the selector (here `.frame`) of the element you want to link it to. I.E. this button will toggle the visibility of all elements with the class name `.frame`.

---

### Demo with your `svg` drawing

In the demo below, I have added two buttons linked to two groups of `svg` elements. Click <kbd>Show code snippet</kbd> > <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> > <kbd>Full page</kbd> to preview:

```js
const hide = e => e.style.display = 'none'
const show = e => e.style.display = ''
const toggleHide = function(selector) {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].forEach(e => e.style.display ? show(e) : hide(e))
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <SVG width="780" height="600">
<rect x="0" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="55" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="110" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="165" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="220" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="275" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="330" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="385" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="440" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="495" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="550" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="605" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="660" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="715" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
<rect x="770" y="0" height="600" width="55"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: none"/>
<rect x="0" y="50" height="15" width="825"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: none"/>
<rect x="0" y="535" height="15" width="825"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: none"/>

<rect class="frame" x="550" y="50" height="500" width="230"
        style="stroke:#000000; stroke-width: 5; fill: none"/>
<rect x="440" y="0" height="600" width="1"
        style="stroke:#000000; stroke-width: 3; fill: none"/>

<rect x="550" y="50" height="15" width="15"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="550" y="535" height="15" width="15"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="765" y="50" height="15" width="15"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="765" y="535" height="15" width="15"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="550" y="300" height="15" width="15"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="765" y="300" height="15" width="15"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="110" y="50" height="15" width="15"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="110" y="535" height="15" width="15"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="408" y="50" height="15" width="15"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
<rect x="408" y="535" height="15" width="15"
        style="stroke:#000000; fill: #101111"/>
  <line class="segments" x1="55" y1="55" x2="550" y2="550"
      style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;
      stroke-width: 6px;
      stroke-dasharray: 10 5"/>
  <line class="segments" x1="550" y1="55" x2="55" y2="550"
      style="stroke: #000000; fill:none;
      stroke-width: 6px;
      stroke-dasharray: 10 5"/>
  
  <text x="400" y="620" fill="Red">7,8 m</text>
  <text x="835" y="300" fill="Red">6 m</text>
  
  <defs>
    <marker id="beginArrow" 
     markerWidth="9" markerHeight="9" 
     refX="0" refY="4" 
     orient="auto">
        <path d="M0,4 L8,0 L8,8 L0,4" style="fill: #c40d0d;" />
    </marker>
    <marker id="endArrow" 
     markerWidth="9" markerHeight="9" 
     refX="8" refY="4" 
     orient="auto">
        <path d="M0,0 L8,4 L0,8 L0,0" style="fill: #c40d0d;" />
    </marker>
</defs>
<line x1="0"  y1="630" x2="825"   y2="630" 
 style="stroke:#c40d0d;
 marker-start: url(#beginArrow);
   marker-end: url(#endArrow);"/>
<defs>
    <marker id="beginArrow2" 
     markerWidth="9" markerHeight="9" 
     refX="0" refY="4" 
     orient="auto">
        <path d="M0,4 L8,0 L8,8 L0,4" style="fill: #c40d0d;" />
    </marker>
    <marker id="endArrow2" 
     markerWidth="9" markerHeight="9" 
     refX="8" refY="4" 
     orient="auto">
        <path d="M0,0 L8,4 L0,8 L0,0" style="fill: #c40d0d;" />
    </marker>
</defs>
<line x1="865"  y1="0" x2="865"   y2="600" 
 style="stroke:#c40d0d;
 marker-start: url(#beginArrow);
   marker-end: url(#endArrow);"/>
   
    
</SVG>

  <p>click on the buttons to remove some parts of the shed</p>

  <button onclick="toggleHide('.segments')">Toggle bars</button>
  <button onclick="toggleHide('.frame')">Toggle frame</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Very good answer thank you very much. I have one quick question for the javascript method. what is the meaning of the ... before document?

Comment: @kristheman, Glad I could help. `document.querySelector(<some selector>)`  returns a `NodeList` of `Nodes`. By using the [spread syntax: `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) I'm able to unwrap this `NodeList` into an actual `Array` object. Which then allows to call in methods like map(), forEach() since it's an `Array`... Personally, I  prefer using this than having a loop accessing each item of the selection: it's cleaner.

Comment: Can I make this work with a script tag, and adding the function to my HTML file? Thank you very much for your explanation

Comment: Sure: just put the JavaScript code in between `<script>` and `</script>`.